# how to multi task on iPhone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to be able to multitask in Matt Gallagher's AudioStream iphone application which can be found over here http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html I tried uibackground by adding to info.plist but it isn't working any ideas on how to make it work? I did read the apple documentation but I have failed to find anything. any code would be appritated

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>voip</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: if its not working then please use this repo from github which is advaced of matt gallagher's audio streamer, it works fine for me - https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer